# text between two xml tags

Tags: python, xml, regex, shell

I would like to get the text between two xml tags either using shell or python commands. For example input:

```
<Name input="sentence">
    <Words>
        <Z 2="x">I</Z>
        <Z 2="x">like</Z>
        <Z 2="x">to</Z>
        <Z 2="x">eat</Z>
        <Z 2="x">food</Z>
     </Words>
</Name>
<Name input="sentence">
    <Words>
        <Z 2="x">Sam's</Z>
        <Z 2="x">food</Z>
        <Z 2="x">is</Z>
        <Z 2="x">best</Z>
    </Words>
</Name>
```

I would like the output to be:

```
I like to eat food
Sam's food best
```

Basically the  tag specifies the start of a new sentence and the  specifies the words I would like to reconstruct it with. I have many of these sentence. Any suggestions? I was thinking about either using sed or re class in python but I couldn't come up with a solution. Thanks!

Comment: How do you have access to these xml tags?  Are they stored in a text file?  Or could they perhaps be represented as strings in python?  As a side note, most people on SO like to see that you've first made an attempt to solve a programming problem with some sample code or at least psuedo code.

Comment: yes they are stored in a text file. I'm attempting to solve the problem but suggestions of what tools to use would be really useful

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/14122

Comment: ...and, if in Python, use your choice of XML-parsing libraries; in lxml, f'rinstance, `tree.xpath('//Name/Words//text()')` will return all text nodes (strings) under the Words tag.

Comment: @user3750474 Would you mind if I make your XML correct XML document by changing   `<Z 2="x">I</Z>`
into   `<Z x="2">I</Z>` or even into `<Z>I</Z>` as the attributes do not relate to the core of the
question?

Answer (score 3):

## Using `lxml` XPath

Having corrected XML document in file "xmldoc.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <Name input="sentence">
    <Words>
      <Z>I</Z>
      <Z>like</Z>
      <Z>to</Z>
      <Z>eat</Z>
      <Z>food</Z>
    </Words>
  </Name>
  <Name input="sentence">
    <Words>
      <Z>Sam's</Z>
      <Z>food</Z>
      <Z>is</Z>
      <Z>best</Z>
    </Words>
  </Name>
</root>
```

we can use `xpath` on parsed document:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> for word in etree.parse("xmldoc.xml").xpath("//Words"):
...     print " ".join(word.xpath(".//Z/text()"))
...
I like to eat food
Sam's food is best
```

## Comments

- original XML in OP is broken, attributes are not allowed to start with numbers.
- `lxml` is to be installed, it is not part of Python stdlib. However, it offers so many practical
  functins (better XPath, validation against schemas ...), that it is worth installing (I consider
  `lxml` standard part of my Python environment).
- `etree.parse` is able parsing file-like object or content of file passed as argument.
- `.xpath("//Words")` is necessary to separate sentences to different groups.
- the dot at `word.xpath(".//Z/text()")` is important, it instructs XPath to evaluate the expression
  relative to current element.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example using `xml.etree.ElementTree` https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#

inputxml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Name input="sentence">
    <Words>
        <Z>I</Z>
        <Z>like</Z>
        <Z>to</Z>
        <Z>eat</Z>
        <Z>food</Z>
    </Words>
</Name>
```

XMLParseWords.py

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

XML_file = 'inputxml.xml'
tree = ET.parse(XML_file)
root = tree.getroot()
outputString = ""
for word in root.findall('./Words/Z'):
    outputString += word.text + " "
print outputString
```

When you run this it will output `I like to eat food`. As long as you know the structure of the xml file that you are parsing it should be fairly straightforward to grab the elements that you are looking for.  I suggest first reading the pydoc that i linked earlier to get a understanding of how `xml.etree.ElementTree` works.

Comment: That would not work for the input the OP provided. `ElementTree` says it is an invalid XML document.

Comment: Haha yea, that's why I edited his XML.  If OP's XML is not formated correctly that should be addressed before trying to parse it.

Comment: @alecxe, ...because the input the OP provided isn't XML at all. The safe thing to assume from that -- when the OP explicitly claims that they're working with XML, as here -- is that the input was poorly anonymized, not that one needs to handle content that isn't XML.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes, this is why I don't think both of the answers are good enough to be claimed helpful here. Changing the OP's input is really not a good practice for SO :)

Comment: @alecxe So what do you propose to provide as an answer? Providing a parser to really broken XML document? Or closing the question as unclear? To me both options seems useless. Correcting broken input is part of an answer followed by using it.

Comment: @JanVlcinsky Personally I think that instead of posting an answer, it would be worth using comments to let the user know that it is really a broken XML and ask, where it is coming from etc - elaborate more with the OP. Both solutions don't directly apply to the user's input and this is a key point here. On the other hand, I understand the motivation to help and the idea of contribution. It's just my opinion, no offense and nothing personal.